# Why would a return of an array cause a transaction?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

library Set {
  // We define a new struct datatype that will be used to
  // hold its data in the calling contract.
  struct Data { mapping(uint => bool) flags; }

  // Note that the first parameter is of type "storage
  // reference" and thus only its storage address and not
  // its contents is passed as part of the call.  This is a
  // special feature of library functions.  It is idiomatic
  // to call the first parameter `self`, if the function can
  // be seen as a method of that object.
  function insert(Data storage self, uint value)
      public
      returns (bool)
  {
      if (self.flags[value])
          return false; // already there
      self.flags[value] = true;
      return true;
  }

  function remove(Data storage self, uint value)
      public
      returns (bool)
  {
      if (!self.flags[value])
          return false; // not there
      self.flags[value] = false;
      return true;
  }

  function contains(Data storage self, uint value)
      public
      view
      returns (bool)
  {
      return self.flags[value];
  }
}
```

I used that standard code, and then coded this -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

import "./Set.sol";

contract d3 {
    Set.Data knownValues;

    function register(uint value) public {
        // The library functions can be called without a
        // specific instance of the library, since the
        // "instance" will be the current contract.
        require(Set.insert(knownValues, value));
    }
    function contains(uint value) public returns (bool) {
        return Set.contains(knownValues, value);
    }
    // In this contract, we can also directly access knownValues.flags, if we want.
}
```

When I run contains, I get a txn, but I did not expect that, and the return seems to be only the hash of the txn -

```
> con.contains(1)
"0x9fe6c523431046eb803488441a49b3d9da5aa571c68bbe2cb6f6296a2b489a43"

> eth.getTransaction("0x9fe6c523431046eb803488441a49b3d9da5aa571c68bbe2cb6f6296a2b489a43")
{
  blockHash: "0xde9b338d4706c2d87f2da7ad220f256be6d4296587afe4525d236204bf7ce709",
  blockNumber: 147826,
  from: "0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 100000000000,
  hash: "0x9fe6c523431046eb803488441a49b3d9da5aa571c68bbe2cb6f6296a2b489a43",
  input: "0xc34052e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  nonce: 364,
  r: "0x8377c621b21d9f272e47783f06e7bd206be3d3ee2b1996e48eebf93bc921ece5",
  s: "0x35a552969fc5dab8f8c245a503258fde5ef01076999003379fe28ceeb94430f6",
  to: "0xb7238164d1719ca660575af7aa3202aff820dfbc",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x2b694",
  value: 0
}
```

Two observations:
1. No bool is returned.
2. A txn is created.

Does this make any sense to anyone?

Comment: Have you tried adding `constant`/`view` to `contains`?

Comment: That worked! I assumed the compiler would simply detect the function only returned - apparently not. Do you want to add the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `view` modifier so web3 knows to send a call instead of a transaction to the contract.